# Automatically save files after multi-file search/replace

Tags: query-replace, query-replace-regexp

How can I get GNU Emacs to automatically save all the files I've changed after doing a [multi-file search/replace with query-replace-regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replacing-text-across-multiple-files.html)? Right now I have to switch back to the buffer for every individual file and save by hand whenever I do multi-file search and replace, which is just plain annoying.

Comment: Not what you asked for but `save-some-buffers` (bound to `C-x s` in vanilla emacs) will save you some time.

Answer (score 3):

You could trigger `save-buffer` after the replace. I believe the following should work:

`(add-hook 'replace-update-post-hook 'save-buffer)`